# Creating a rails path for a known action based on current record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As part of my template I show some automatic links which are created in the application_controller. Some of these links will offer a navigation direct from a show page to a corresponding edit page, and a few similar things.

My current code includes:

```
nav_links  << {:name=>:edit,:url=>url_for(:action => :edit)}
```

This works great apart from I have child resources defined in my routes.rb file.

In this case instead of navigating to:

```
a/1/b/2/edit
```

It navigates to

```
b/2/edit
```

which isn't a valid route.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated. I'm keen to avoid special case where at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

A little confused - why not just use the routes resources define for you. Given that you mentioned 'child resource', I can assume you've declared these resources? If so - you should have a host of routes available to you...

- Fire off 'rake routes' from the command line
- Find your route
- It will most likely take two arguments and look something like this (roughly):

  edit_a_b GET /a/:a_id/b/:id
- Just use edit_a_b_url(@a, @b)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Because I'm doing this in application controller this code is run for every controller, and so I need to find the edit action for the current controller, not a known one.